# HAproxy + Varnish

Tags: haproxy, varnish

As seen on the picture below, this is my current planned setup, I need to tell HAproxy to send users to the Varnish, if HAproxy detects a cache-miss, or dynamic/pseudo-dynamic content, it will send the user to the web servers, and then cache the content.

I'm very new to Varnish and the entire caching topic, so this is the first setup I'm doing with a caching layer!

Any input on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> if HAproxy detects a cache-miss, or dynamic/pseudo-dynamic content

Why not just have HAproxy all pointing at Varnish which then fetch from Apache  servers? Seems like you are introducing an extra step to make HAproxy detect cache behavior when Varnish is able to do this by default.

I would imagine a setup like the following would be more logical.

HAproxy -> Varnish -> Apache

Comment: I have been considering that, but I want to keep Varnish separate, not directly involved with the webservers, in the case of a failure, I want haproxy to ignore the cache and serve from the web servers themselves, but if there is a cache available, it would use that instead. A setup like you showed, could produce a second point of failure, if the varnish instances fail, I could potentially sit there with webservers unable to speak with the load balancer. By separating it and making the cache optional, by telling it to communicate with haproxy, I believe I can avoid that. Correct me if Im wrong